# TensorFlow Estimator BestExporter event_file_pattern doesn't do anything

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I have a [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub) with a very simple demo `Estimator` for the sole purpose of learning / understanding the `Estimator` api with the goal of making a convention for a plug-and-play model with common bells and whistles of the trade in tack (e.g. early stopping if the validation set stops improving, exporting the model, etc).

In the [cell](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub#scrollTo=xGQI18i47BHQ&line=2&uniqifier=1) where I define the [`BestExporter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BestExporter) I have:

```
exporter = tf.estimator.BestExporter(
    name="best_exporter",
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn,
    # event_file_pattern="model_*", # <--- doesn't do anything?
    exports_to_keep=5
) # this will keep the 5 best checkpoints
```

which currently exports my best models under

```
<MODEL_DIR>/export/best_exporter/<some_number>
```

where  `MODEL_DIR=./test` (under the cell `setup > constants` and specified in the `RunConfig` set in `estimator functions > run config`)

If I uncomment `event_file_pattern="model_*",` I expected to see my model be exported to `<MODEL_DIR>/export/best_exporter/model_<number>`, but it doesn't.

So how do I specify what my models should be called?

For example, in the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub) I track the metrics `mse` and `mae`.

How would I get the 5 best `exports_to_keep` be saved as:

```
MODEL_DIR/export/best_exporter/<model_name>_mae_<mae-rounded-to-3-decimals>
```

?